# Docker Kitematic connect ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: docker, windows-10, virtualbox, boot2docker

Starting Kitematic on Windows 10 gives me this error

`Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 198.105.254.24:2375`

I'm already running 'default' vm in VirtualBox. The only way to start Kitematic is to hit the 'USE VIRTUALBOX' button.

Why won't Kitematic start unless I click 'USE VIRTUALBOX' button? I've already got VirtualBox running the 'default' vm successfully...

[image: ETIMEDOUT]

Answer (score 0):

I commented on the docker / kitematic Github issues page and one of the participants told me to simply click `USE VIRTUALBOX` button to use VirtualBox on Windows since they are in favor of Docker for Windows.

https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/1029#issuecomment-226974739

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off Hyper-V in your system, then reboot and click run VirtualBox next time.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. Below solution worked for me:

1. Deleted the folder `C:\Users\{Account_name}\.docker`
2. Clicked on the "Retry setup" button on Kitematic. It re-created `C:\Users\{Account_name}\.docker` with a new default machine. `Error : connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.xxx.xxx:2376` disappeared but faced new error: `C:\Users\{Account_name}\.docker\machine\machines\default\ca.pem does not exist`
3. Copied all certificate files from `C:\Users\{Account_name}\.docker\machine\certs` to `C:\Users\{Account_name}\.docker\machine\machines\default`. Then I got error
   `Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.xxx.xxx:2376"`
4. Regenerated certificates for default machine by running below command on Command Prompt.

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs default
```

It showed below output:

> Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): y
> Regenerating TLS certificates
> Waiting for SSH to be available...
> Detecting the provisioner...
> Copying certs to the local machine directory...
> Copying certs to the remote machine...
> Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...

After this, I was able to access default machine through Kitematic GUI. I figured that issue was due to TLS connection and these steps fixed it.